# Molding/shaping sodium polyacrylate?

Tags: polymers

I've been researching sodium polyacrylate, which normally comes as those "aqua gems" for plants, or fake snow. Specifically, I've been hoping to find information on molding, casting, or otherwise giving shape to the material - nothing terribly complex, just things like simple stars for example (while hoping no one mistakes them for Jell-o jigglers).

So far, I've only been able to determine that sodium polyacrylate is *not* a thermoplastic, so the obvious solution won't work. I heard from one source that those toys that grow in water may be made of the same stuff combined with another polymer, but couldn't get any further leads on the subject.

So the question is, what solutions are available for giving sodium polyacrylate a defined shape, while keeping most of its absorption/growth properties?